# WPF ComboBox with PART_Editor as Item of Itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, tags, word-wrap

I'm trying to implement a Token(Tag)Control in WPF.
The control itself is working, but I need the possibility to wrap the PART_Editor of a ComboBox behind the last item of a listbox. On overflow the items are wrapping into a new line.

My Code looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditTemplate">

        <!-- EditElementMinWidth ist die Mindestbreite des Eingabebereiches für weitere Tags -->
        <WrapPanel>
            <ListBox Style="{StaticResource WrapTagPanelListBoxStyle}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaggedItems,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource WrapTagPanelItemContainerStyle}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplate}"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>

            <TextBox Name="PART_Editor" Style="{DynamicResource {themes:TextEditThemeKey ResourceKey=TextStyle}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     GotFocus="UIElement_OnGotFocus" helpers:EditorMarginHelper.Margin="2,2,2,2,0,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The EditTemplate is the Template of the EditValue of a DevExpress ComboBox-Control.

How can I resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a working solution. I merged the ItemsSource of the ListBox with the PART_Editor by using a CompositeCollection.

EDIT:

Comment: can you post the right code? I have the same issue!

Comment: I added it to my last post.